# Why Opencover with MSTest does not execute and says "access is denied"?

Tags: mstest, code-coverage, opencover

I am using open cover with MSTest.
I am a new users and trying to get hang of Opencover.
I have tried with MSTest and MSTest is working fine with my new project in Vs2010. When I am executing following test using MStest it is working fine:

Command line run of MS Test :

```
MSTest /testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\<<MYuserName>>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VoterDetails>
MSTest /testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest 
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Loading VoterDetails.vsmdi...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Passed                (DOBTest/)UT_voterDOB.VoterValidationTest.validateVoterDOB
Test
1/1 test(s) Passed

Summary
-------
Test Run Completed.
Passed  1
---------
Total   1
Results file:  C:\Users\<<MYuserName>>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VoterDetails\TestResults\<<MYuserName>>.trx
Test Settings: Local
```

But When I am executing following command then I am getting following result:
I am posting all combinations I have tried:

```
C:\Users\<<MyUserName>>\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover>OpenCover.Console.exe 
-register:user 
-target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"              
-targetargs:"/testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest" 
-filter:+[VoterDetails]*
```

Access is denied.

```
C:\Users\<<MyUserName>>\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover>OpenCover.Console.exe 
-register:-arch:32 
-target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" 
-targetargs:"/testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest" 
-filter:+[VoterDetails]*  -output:coverage.xml
```

Access is denied.

```
 C:\Users\<<MyUserName>>\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover>OpenCover.Console.exe 
 -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" 
 -targetargs:"/testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest" 
 -filter:+[VoterDetails]*  
 -output:coverage.xml 
 -mergebyhash
```

Access is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How will MSTEST know where to find VoterDetails.vsmdi when you are running in the wrong folder; try running from OpenCover from

`C:\Users\<<MYuserName>>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VoterDetails`

i.e.

`C:\Users\<<MyUserName>>\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover>OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user ...`

also `-arch:32` is not a valid option for OpenCover

Comment: If I understand this correctly my Command prompt now looks like :   
C:\Users\Kolatkap\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VoterDetails>C:\Users\<<MyUsers>>\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" -register:user -t
argetargs:"/testmetadata:VoterDetails.vsmdi /testlist:DOBTest" -output:coverage.
xml   Still the error is same "Access is denied"

Comment: Then I suggest you try the `-targetdir:` option

Comment: i will try and get back to you!